# Returning the Python floating point number from the string representation of its sign, exponent and significant

Tags: python, floating-point

In Python, is there a built-in solution to have a floating point number out from the string representation of its sign, exponent and significant?

Say I have

```
sign='0', exponent='127', significant='1.00000011920928955078125'
```

How can I get the represented floating point number using some built-in function of Python?

Comment: I don't think there is such a function in Python. You could always just write `(-1)**float(sign) * float(significant) * 2**float(exponent)`.

Comment: Where does your exponent come from? Does it represent a power of 2, or a power of 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply combine the variables to one string:

```
float('%s%sE%s' % ('+' if sign == '0' else '-', significant, exponent))
```